# Can only get a value of false to return when accessing Sensor.TYPE_TEMPERATURE

Tags: android, sensors, temperature

The Google doc's cover every one of the sensors except the temperature sensor, but continue to say that you can access that data...........it's aggrevating as heck, the doc's are very good in some parts and very bad in others.

I have no problem getting the data from the other sensors so I'm quite sure my code is good.  Would love some insite on how to retrieve the temp sensors value(s).

Comment: SetCPU does this, but it might be a root-only feature.  If you can't find an email here you might want to shoot the developer of that app an email.

Answer (score 0):

In Android, when polling for a sensor's data,
a value of '**False**' is returned to your app when no events for your particular sensor have been reported.

Please verify that your low-level implementation is working fine.

Log your kernel-drivers and watch if they are reporting events as expected by the Android Sensor HAL.

GoodLUCK!
-CVS